# How to connect points to line in Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, geometry-conversion

I am using Mapinfo and Mapbasic.

I have all the points stored in a DBMS. 
I have four columns with four points longitude and latitude.
Is there any way to connect the points?

I am using Mapinfo 10.5 with MySql as database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Points to Lines to connect your points.

See MapBasic downloads - by Bill Williams

http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l/browse_thread/thread/258895182fe36432