# Using MapInfo SQL?

Tags: sql, mapinfo

I am trying to create a map of U.S. counties that shows migration patterns.

I have a table of all US counties and a table that has migration information.

Some counties do not have migration, hence when I match the counties by fips in the two data sets the counties that do not have migration are missing in the map.

How can I keep all the counties (in first table) even if not included in second table?

Answer (score 2):

I would try using a LEFT JOIN.

SELECT  
FROM Table_A A 
LEFT JOIN Table_B B 
ON A.Key = B.Key

[Visual Representation of SQL Statemets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

[MapInfo Specific Tutorial on Joins](http://www.pbinsight.com/support/education/video-tutorials/detail/joining-tables/)

Comment: Then there's the mighty Mapbasic Createlines command http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/13214/14242